# Scala: is it possible to override default case class constructor?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Just wondering if this is possible.
What I would actually like to do is check and possibly modify one of the arguments before it is stored as a val.

Alternatively, I could use an overload and make the default constructor private. In which case I would also like to make private the default factory constructor in the companion object, how would I do that?

Many thanks.

Adam

edit: well i figured out that making the default constructor private also makes the default factory constructor private, so i have a solution, i'm still interested to know if the default constructor is overridable though

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A case class is meant to be used to define algebraic data types, so an added constructor that alters the caller's arguments a bit of a lie.

As far as validating arguments goes, that can be done in the primary constructor using `assert` or `require`.

Comment: @adam77 To reframe your initial statement as a question, "Can I check and possibly modify a [case class parameter]?" The answer is yes. I just posted the details on a related question located here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538287/501113

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The presence of secondary case class constructors don't cause the compiler to produce additional factory methods in the class's companion, so you won't get the convenience of `CaseClaseName(«secondary constructor parameter list»>)` for creating them. You'll have to use the `new` keyword.

It's better to put the sort of logic you're describing in alternate factory methods in the companion object and stick to using the primary constructor.

Answer (score 25):

You do not have the option of changing the way the default constructor stores its parameters (e.g. by modifying the parameters before they are stored as `val`s) but you do have the option of throwing an exception if the parameters are wrong (this will occur after the parameters are stored)

```
case class Foo(x:Int){
    if (x<0) throw SomeException;
}
```

You also have the option of implementing additional constructors that call the first constructor

```
case class Foo(x:Int){
     def this(x:Int,y:Int) = this(x+y)
}
```

but those don't get factory methods.

You could easily create the factory method yourself by adding it to the companion object

```
object Foo{
     def apply(x:Int,y:Int) = new Foo(x,y)
}
```

Anything else more complicated than that, and you have to forgo the case class and implement it's parts on your own: `apply`, `unapply`, `equals`, and `hashCode`. *Programming in Scala* talks about how to do all of these, giving good formulas for `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: It is possible to safely change parameters before they are stored in the case class. And you can still do quite a few more complicated things without forgoing all the benefits of case classes. I have just detailed my solution on another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538287/501113

Answer (score 3):

You can overload constructors.  It's the same as in C++ or Java.  Simply make another constructor.

```
class Foo( _input:Int ){
    def this() = this( 0 )
}
```

Or you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400794/overload-constructor-for-scalas-case-classes) SO post.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is override not overload.

Comment: No constructor can be overridden, since they're not inherited to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn a regular class into a pseudo-case-class by writing your own `apply` (for the factory) and `unapply` (for the pattern match) methods in the companion object.  Or, you could simply write a named factory method in the case class's companion object.