# What's the difference between => , ()=>, and Unit=>

Tags: scala

I'm trying to represent a function that takes no arguments and returns no value (I'm simulating the setTimeout function in JavaScript, if you must know.)

```
case class Scheduled(time : Int, callback :  => Unit)
```

doesn't compile, saying " `val' parameters may not be call-by-name"

```
case class Scheduled(time : Int, callback :  () => Unit)
```

compiles, but has to be invoked strangely, instead of

```
Scheduled(40, { println("x") } )
```

I have to do this

```
Scheduled(40, { () => println("x") } )
```

What also works is

```
class Scheduled(time : Int, callback :  Unit => Unit)
```

but is invoked in an even-less-sensible way

```
 Scheduled(40, { x : Unit => println("x") } )
```

(What would a variable of type Unit be?)  What I *want* of course is a constructor that can be invoke the way I would invoke it if it were an ordinary function:

```
 Scheduled(40, println("x") )
```

Give baby his bottle!

Comment: Another way to use case classes with by-name parms, is to put them in a secondary parameter list, e.g. `case class Scheduled(time: Int)(callback: => Unit)`. This works because the secondary parameter list is not exposed publicly, nor is it included in the generated `equals`/`hashCode` methods.

Comment: A few more interesting aspects regarding the differences between by-name parameters and 0-arity functions are found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32802104/302793) and the answer. It's actually what I was looking for when I found this question.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

### Call-by-Name: => Type

The `=> Type` notation stands for call-by-name, which is one of the [many ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) parameters can be passed. If you aren't familiar with them, I recommend taking some time to read that wikipedia article, even though nowadays it is mostly call-by-value and call-by-reference.

What it means is that what is passed is *substituted* for the value name inside the function. For example, take this function:

```
def f(x: => Int) = x * x
```

If I call it like this

```
var y = 0
f { y += 1; y }
```

Then the code will execute like this

```
{ y += 1; y } * { y += 1; y }
```

Though that raises the point of what happens if there's a identifier name clash. In traditional call-by-name, a mechanism called capture-avoiding substitution takes place to avoid name clashes. In Scala, however, this is implemented in another way with the same result -- identifier names inside the parameter can't refer to or shadow identifiers in the called function.

There are some other points related to call-by-name that I'll speak of after explaining the other two.

### 0-arity Functions: () => Type

The syntax `() => Type` stands for the type of a `Function0`. That is, a function which takes no parameters and returns something. This is equivalent to, say, calling the method `size()` -- it takes no parameters and returns a number.

It is interesting, however, that this syntax is very similar to the syntax for a *anonymous function literal*, which is the cause for some confusion. For example,

```
() => println("I'm an anonymous function")
```

is an anonymous function literal of arity 0, whose *type* is

```
() => Unit
```

So we could write:

```
val f: () => Unit = () => println("I'm an anonymous function")
```

It is important not to confuse the type with the value, however.

### Unit => Type

This is actually just a `Function1`, whose first parameter is of type `Unit`. Other ways to write it would be `(Unit) => Type` or `Function1[Unit, Type]`. The thing is... this is unlikely to ever be what one wants. The `Unit` type's main purpose is indicating a value one is not interested in, so doesn't make sense to *receive* that value.

Consider, for instance,

```
def f(x: Unit) = ...
```

What could one possibly do with `x`? It can only have a single value, so one need not receive it. One possible use would be chaining functions returning `Unit`:

```
val f = (x: Unit) => println("I'm f")
val g = (x: Unit) => println("I'm g")
val h = f andThen g
```

Because `andThen` is only defined on `Function1`, and the functions we are chaining are returning `Unit`, we had to define them as being of type `Function1[Unit, Unit]` to be able to chain them.

### Sources of Confusion

The first source of confusion is thinking the similarity between type and literal that exists for 0-arity functions also exists for call-by-name. In other words, thinking that, because

```
() => { println("Hi!") }
```

is a literal for `() => Unit`, then

```
{ println("Hi!") }
```

would be a literal for `=> Unit`. It is not. That is a *block of code*, not a literal.

Another source of confusion is that `Unit` type's *value* is written `()`, which looks like a 0-arity parameter list (but it is not).

Comment: I may have to be the first to down-vote after two years.  Somebody is wondering about case => syntax on Christmas, and I can't recommend this answer as canonical and complete! What is the world coming to? Maybe the Mayans were just off by a week. Did they figure in leap years correctly? Daylight savings?

Comment: @som-snytt Well, the question didn't ask about `case ... =>`, so I didn't mention it. Sad but true. :-)

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral could you please explain " That is a block of code, not a literal." part. So what is the exact different between two?

Comment: @nish1013 A "literal" is a value (the integer `1`, the character `'a'`, the string `"abc"`, or the function `() => println("here")`, for some examples). It can be passed as argument, stored in variables, etc. A "block of code" is a syntactical delimitation of statements -- it isn't a value, it can't be passed around, or anything like that.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral many thanks for your respond."A "block of code" is a syntactical delimitation of statements -- it isn't a value, it can't be passed around"

Please refer to breakable function call in below link's example. 

https://github.com/nraychaudhuri/scalainaction/blob/master/chap02/breakable.scala

So isn't it pass around a "block of code" ?

Comment: @nish1013 No, it isn't. See pass-by-name at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: what's the difference between `Unit => Type` and `() => Type`?

Comment: @Alex That's the same difference as `(Unit) => Type` vs `() => Type` -- the first is a `Function1[Unit, Type]`, while the second is a `Function0[Type]`.

Answer (score 39):

```
case class Scheduled(time : Int, callback :  => Unit)
```

The `case` modifier makes implicit `val` out of each argument to the constructor.  Hence (as someone noted) if you remove `case` you can use a call-by-name parameter.  The compiler could probably allow it anyway, but it might surprise people if it created `val callback` instead of morphing into `lazy val callback`.

When you change to `callback: () => Unit` now your case just takes a function rather than a call-by-name parameter.  Obviously the function can be stored in `val callback` so there's no problem.

The easiest way to get what you want (`Scheduled(40, println("x") )` where a call-by-name parameter is used to pass a lambda) is probably to skip the `case` and explicitly create the `apply` that you couldn't get in the first place:

```
class Scheduled(val time: Int, val callback: () => Unit) {
    def doit = callback()
}

object Scheduled {
    def apply(time: Int, callback: => Unit) =
        new Scheduled(time, { () => callback })
}
```

In use:

```
scala> Scheduled(1234, println("x"))
res0: Scheduled = Scheduled@5eb10190

scala> Scheduled(1234, println("x")).doit
x
```

Comment: Why not keep it a case-class and just override the default apply? Also, the compiler cannot translate a by-name to a lazy val, since they have inherently different semantics, lazy is at-most-once and by-name has at-every-reference

Comment: @ViktorKlang How can you override a case class's default apply method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660975/scala-is-it-possible-to-override-default-case-class-constructor

Comment: object ClassName {
  def apply(…): … = …
}

Comment: Four years later and I realize that the answer I selected only answered the question in the title, not the one I actually had (which this one does answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the question, you want to simulate SetTimeOut function in JavaScript. Based on previous answers, I write following code:

```
class Scheduled(time: Int, cb: => Unit) {
  private def runCb = cb
}

object Scheduled {
  def apply(time: Int, cb: => Unit) = {
    val instance = new Scheduled(time, cb)
    Thread.sleep(time*1000)
    instance.runCb
  }
}
```

In REPL, we can get something like this:

```
scala> Scheduled(10, println("a")); Scheduled(1, println("b"))
a
b
```

Our simulation doesn't behave exactly the same as SetTimeOut, because our simulation is blocking function, but SetTimeOut is non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way (just don't want to break apply):

```
case class Thing[A](..., lazy: () => A) {}
object Thing {
  def of[A](..., a: => A): Thing[A] = Thing(..., () => a)
}
```

and call it

```
Thing.of(..., your_value)
```