# Scala - parameter of type T or => T

Tags: scala, function-parameter

Is there any difference between the following

```
def foo(s: String) = { ... }
```

and

```
def foo(s: => String) { ... }
```

both these definitions accept "sss" as parameter.

Comment: This might be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4545703/298389

Comment: Did you mean to put an '=' sign before the curly braces on both functions? The answers below assume this. It makes an important difference but would be a matter for a separate discussion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An argument `String` is a [by-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value#Call_by_value) parameter, `=> String` is a [by-name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_name#Call_by_name) parameter. In the first case, the string is passed in, in the second a so-called [thunk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28functional_programming%29) which *evaluates to* a `String` whenever it is used.

```
def stringGen: String = util.Random.nextInt().toString

def byValue(s: String) =
  println("We have a '" + s + "' and a '" + s + "'")

def byName(s: => String) =
  println("We have a '" + s + "' and a '" + s + "'")

byValue(stringGen)  // constant value
byName (stringGen)  // evaluated twice
```

Often a by-name parameter is not used to evaluate it several times, but to *lazily* evaluate it once.

```
def logMessage = {
  println("Calculating log message...")
  new java.util.Date().toString
}

def log(enabled: Boolean, message: => String): Unit = {
  lazy val fullMessage = "LOG: " + message
  println("Test")
  if (enabled) println(fullMessage)
}

log(false, logMessage)
log(true , logMessage)
```

Answer (score 2):

In many cases they are the same, but

The => passes by name

The first passes by value

Comment: => means "by name" not "by reference"

Comment: sorry about that, I just edited the answer. I had just answered another question about passing by value / reference and had it in my head.

Comment: They're not the same.  They're two different things.