# Declaring function as parameter in method signature

Tags: function, scala, parameters

Slowly moving into scala.  Can either of these be done (apparently not the way I have them here)?

```
def genericFunc(param1:String, param2:String, specificFunc(param2:SpecficType):[T]):[T] =
{
    val interim:SpecificType = makeSpecificType(param1,param2)
    specificFunc(interim)
}


def genericFunc(param1:String, param2:String,specificFunc(param2:SpecficType):Object):Object ={
    val interim:SpecificType = makeSpecificType(param1,param2)
    specificFunc(interim)
}
```

or does the specificFunc need to be a trait/interface.

Comment: See also ["What's the difference between => , ()=>, and Unit=>"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4543228/298389) for different kinds of functions you can pass-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a function as an argument to another function you should have a following method signature:

```
def genericFunc[T](param1:String, param2:String, specificFunc: SpecficType => T): T = ???
```

`SpecficType => T` - is a function type which means that it needs a function which takes one argument of type `SpecficType` and returns a value of generic type `T`. Example:

```
def fromString[A](str: String, f: String => A) = f(str)

fromString("hello", str => str.toCharArray.sum.toInt)
```

you can optimize this futher:

```
fromString("hello", _.toCharArray.sum.toInt)
```

in this case `fromString` is a **higher-order function**. HOF are functions which can:

- take another function as an argument
- return a function

All this stuff is perfectly described in prof. Odersky book on - [Programming in Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644)