# By-name parameters or functions?

Tags: scala

I found out that by-name parameters and functions are very similar. What is the advantage the first  ones against the second ones?

```
object ws1 {
  def myByFunc(f: () => Int) = f()                //> myByFunc: (f: () => Int)Int
  def myByName(f: => Int) = f                     //> myByName: (f: => Int)Int

  def testFunc(a: Int) = a * a                    //> testFunc: (a: Int)Int

  myByFunc(() => testFunc(123))                   //> res0: Int = 15129
  myByName(testFunc(123))                         //> res1: Int = 15129

}
```

**UPDATE**:
Regarding the question of how many times each of them executes:

```
object ws1 {
  def myByFunc(f: () => Int) = {
    println("111111111 myByFunc")
    f()
  }                                               //> myByFunc: (f: () => Int)Int

  def myByName(f: => Int) = {
    println("22222222 myByName")
    f
  }                                               //> myByName: (f: => Int)Int

  def testFunc(a: Int) = a * a                    //> testFunc: (a: Int)Int

  myByFunc(() => testFunc(123))                   //> 111111111 myByFunc
                                                  //| res0: Int = 15129
  myByName(testFunc(123))                         //> 22222222 myByName
                                                  //| res1: Int = 15129
}
```

For some reason they both execute 1 time. Why?

**UPDATE2:**
Neither of them is evaluated:

```
object ws1 {
  def myByFunc(f: () => Int) = {
    println("111111111 myByFunc")
  }                                               //> myByFunc: (f: () => Int)Unit

  def myByName(f: => Int) = {
    println("22222222 myByName")
  }                                               //> myByName: (f: => Int)Unit

  def testFunc(a: Int) = {
    println("hello from test func")
    123456
  }                                               //> testFunc: (a: Int)Int

  myByFunc(() => testFunc(123))                   //> 111111111 myByFunc
  myByName(testFunc(123))                         //> 22222222 myByName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's seems similar but the intent is different :

- `() => Int` is a **function**, more precisely `Function0` : it take no parameter and return an `Int`. The **execution** of the function is triggred by call of f().
- `=> Int` is a **parameter**, passed with a *call-by-name* technique : The **evaluation** will be lazy. The code can never be evaluated : `def myByName(f: => Int) = 1` or be evaluated multiple times : `def myByName(f: => Int) = f * f`.

For a more complete explanation, take a look at this question : [What's the difference between => , ()=>, and Unit=>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit/4545703#4545703)

Comment: isn't `() => Int` lazy? won't `() => Int` be executed several times?

Comment: `() => Int` is not lazy, it's a call-by-value. The value will first be computed and passed to `myByFunc`

Comment: what about the 2nd question?

Comment: It will be executed one and only one time at each call of myByFunc