# By-name parameter vs anonymous function

Tags: scala

What is still unclear for is what's the advantage by-name parameters over anonymous functions in terms of lazy evaluation and other benefits if any:

```
def func1(a: => Int)
def func2(a: () => Int)
```

When should I use the first and when the second one?

This is not the copy of [What's the difference between => , ()=>, and Unit=>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit/4545703#4545703)

Comment: Could you specify what unclear here (check Sources of Confusion) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit/4545703#4545703

Comment: @Yury When should I use the first and when the second one?

Comment: by-name parameters clarify intent that you are evaluating a parameter only when it is used and with no other side effect. For instance, an anonymous function could have a side effect hidden in it: `param: () => Int = () => {println("side effect!"); 3}`

Answer (score 11):

Laziness is the same in the both cases, but there are slight differences. Consider:

```
def generateInt(): Int = { ... }
def byFunc(a: () => Int) { ... }
def byName(a: => Int) { ... }

// you can pass method without
// generating additional anonymous function
byFunc(generateInt)

// but both of the below are the same
// i.e. additional anonymous function is generated
byName(generateInt)
byName(() => generateInt())
```

Functions with call-by-name however is useful for making DSLs. For instance:

```
def measured(block: ⇒ Unit): Long = {
  val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  block
  System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
}

Long timeTaken = measured {
  // any code here you like to measure
  // written just as there were no "measured" around
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
  def func1(a: => Int) {
    val b = a // b is of type Int, and it`s value is the result of evaluation of a
  }

def func2(a: () => Int) {
    val b = a // b is of type Function0 (is a reference to function a)
  }
```

Comment: and so what, what's the difference? I can do val b = a() also.

Answer (score 6):

An example might give a pretty thorough tour of the differences.

Consider that you wanted to write your own version of the veritable `while` loop in Scala.  I know, I know... using `while` in Scala?  But this isn't about functional programming, this is an example that demonstrates the topic well.  So hang with me.  We'll call our own version `whyle`.  Furthermore, we want to implement it *without* using Scala's builtin `while`.  To pull that off we can make our `whyle` construct recursive.  Also, we'll add the `@tailrec` annotation to make sure that our implementation can be used as a real-world substitute for the built-in `while`.  Here's a first go at it:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def whyle(predicate: () => Boolean)(block: () => Unit): Unit = {
  if (predicate()) {
    block()
    whyle(predicate)(block)
  }
}
```

Let's see how this works.  We can pass in parameterized code blocks to `whyle`.  The first is the `predicate` parameterized function.  The second is the `block` parameterized function.  How would we use this?

What we *want* is for our end user to use the `whyle` just like you would the `while` control structure:

```
// Using the vanilla 'while'
var i = 0
while(i < args.length) {
  println(args(i))
  i += 1
}
```

But since our code blocks are *parameterized*, the end-user of our `whyle` loop must add some ugly syntactic sugar to get it to work:

```
// Ouch, our whyle is hideous
var i = 0
whyle( () => i < args.length) { () =>
  println(args(i))
  i += 1
}
```

So.  It appears that if we want the end-user to be able to call our `whyle` loop in a more familiar, native looking style, we'll need to use *parameterless* functions.  But then we have a really big problem.  As soon as you use *parameterless* functions, you can no longer have your cake and eat it too.  You can only eat your cake.  Behold:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def whyle(predicate: => Boolean)(block: => Unit): Unit = {
  if (predicate) {
    block
    whyle(predicate)(block)  // !!! THIS DOESN'T WORK LIKE YOU THINK !!!
  }
}
```

Wow.  Now the user can call our `whyle` loop the way they expect... but our implementation doesn't make any sense.  You have no way of both *calling* a parameterless function and *passing the function itself around* as a value.  You can only call it.  That's what I mean by only eating your cake.  You can't have it, too.  And therefore our recursive implementation now goes out the window.  It only works with the parameterized functions which is unfortunately pretty ugly.

We might be tempted at this point to cheat.  We could rewrite our `whyle` loop to use Scala's built-in `while`:

```
def whyle(pred: => Boolean)(block: => Unit): Unit = while(pred)(block)
```

Now we can use our `whyle` exactly like `while`, because we only needed to be able to eat our cake... we didn't need to have it, too.

```
var i = 0
whyle(i < args.length) {
  println(args(i))
  i += 1
}
```

But we cheated!  Actually, here's a way to have our very own tail-optimized version of the while loop:

```
def whyle(predicate: => Boolean)(block: => Unit): Unit = {
  @tailrec
  def whyle_internal(predicate2: () => Boolean)(block2: () => Unit): Unit = {
    if (predicate2()) {
      block2()
      whyle_internal(predicate2)(block2)
    }
  }
  whyle_internal(predicate _)(block _)
}
```

Can you figure out what we just did??  We have our original (but ugly) parameterized functions in the *inner* function here.  We have it wrapped with a function that takes as arguments parameterless functions.  It then calls the inner function and converts the parameterless functions into parameterized functions (by turning them into partially applied functions).

Let's try it out and see if it works:

```
var i = 0
whyle(i < args.length) {
  println(args(i))
  i += 1
}
```

And it does!

Thankfully, since in Scala we have closures we can clean this up big time:

```
def whyle(predicate: => Boolean)(block: => Unit): Unit = {
  @tailrec
  def whyle_internal: Unit = {
    if (predicate) {
      block
      whyle_internal
    }
  }
  whyle_internal
}
```

Cool.  Anyways, those are some really big differences between parameterless and parameterized functions.  I hope this gives you some ideas!

Comment: However I disagree with your last code (the refactoring with closures). Indeed, when doing `precidate` and `block`, it would be evaluated only once since they are call-by-name parameters. What do you think?

Comment: @Mik378 Thank you very much for the positive feedback!  I created a gist at https://gist.github.com/afazio/4a30e05d5ec8aaab0b7b with a quick script that tests out the last version of the `whyle` loop.  Let me know what you think... and again, thank you!!

Comment: But I must admit, I should clean up my answer... the wording is a bit sloppy. :/

Comment: Actually, you're right. I thought that `block` would be evaluated just once, the first call. But in fact, all the expression designated by block is evaluated each time. So your code is good ;)

Answer (score 1):

The two formats are used interchangeably, but there are some cases where we can use only one of theme.

let's explain by example, suppose that we need to define a case class with two parameters :

```
{
  .
  .
  .
  type Action = () => Unit;

  case class WorkItem(time : Int, action : Action);
  .
  .
  .

}
```

as we can see, the second parametre of the WorkItem class has a type Action.

if we try to replace this parameter with the other format **=>**,

`case class WorkItem1(time : Int, s : => Unit)`  the compiler will show a message error :

> Multiple markers at this line:
>
> `val' parameters may not be call-by-name Call-by-name parameter
>   creation: () ⇒

so as we have see the format **()=>** is more generic and we can use it to define Type, as class field or method parameter, in the other side **=>** format can used as method parameter but not as class field.

> A by-name type, in which the empty parameter list, (), is left out, is only
>   allowed for parameters. There is no such thing as a by-name variable or a
>   by-name field.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the first function definition if you want to pass as the argument an `Int` by name.
Use the second definition if you want the argument to be a parameterless function returning an `Int`.

Comment: and what's the difference?

Comment: And what's the difference between `def func1(a: => Int)` and 
`def func2(a: => String)` ? The argument types are different. Just like in your example.

Comment: that's obvious but that does't answer the question.