# Scala by name versus function parameters

Tags: scala, function, methods, lazy-evaluation, callbyname

This is a named parameter:

```
def foo(bar: => Boolean): Boolean = bar
```

And this is a function parameter:

```
def foo(bar: () => Boolean): Boolean = bar()
```

How do the two declarations differ? Both will be evaluated lazily and each time the parameter is accessed?  Is there an advantage to one syntax or the other?  Would the former connote a pure function versus one with side effects for the latter?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948598/by-name-parameter-vs-anonymous-function), does it answer your question?

Comment: [Another useful link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit?lq=1)

Comment: Yes, it does!  Thank you.  I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit/4545703#4545703 helpful (linked from the topic you supplied).