# Scala - Passing a function to Future.apply

Tags: scala, syntax, semantics

I'm learning Scala and just getting familiar with syntax. I see that `Future.apply` takes a function as the work to do.

The following works perfectly:

```scala
val future = Future { doWork(1) }
```

However just for experimentation I tried some other ways to do it, and neither work appropriately.

```scala
val future = Future(() => doWork(1))
```

This results in the lambda becoming the completion value of the future, instead of the return value of `doWork(1)`.

```scala
val work: () => Int = () => doWork(index)
val future = Future(work)
```

The same situation here. Could someone explain why passing the function as the work to be done is instead resulting in the function actually becoming the return value of the work being done. Also how would I go about this. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [By-name parameter vs anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948598/by-name-parameter-vs-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of method called in `Future {...}` is `def apply[T](body: =>T)` where `=> T` is a `by-name` parameter. See this [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) for more info.

> By-name parameters are only evaluated when used.

In examples

```
Future(() => doWork(1))
```

and

```
val work: () => Int = () => doWork(index)
val future = Future(work)
```

You are passing as `by-name` parameter function of type `() => Int` or same as `Function0[Int]`. This function is returned in the `Future` when `by-name` parameter is evaluated.

The function is not evaluated as `Future` does not call `apply` or `()`.

It will be more understandable if you add type parameters to the `Future` in all examples. If `doWork` returns `Int`. In this case `Future { doWork(1) }` is `Future[Int]` whereas it is `Future[Function0[Int]]` in the second and third examples.

The correct usage would be

```
val work: () => Int = () => doWork(index)
val future = Future(work())
```