# Confused about this Scala syntax

Tags: scala

Could someone please explain this piece of code:

```
val ns: Iterator[Int] = (1 to 3).iterator
ns.map(_ => () => block)
```

where

```
block: => Future[T]
```

Basically I'm just confused about what's going on with the `_`, `=>`, and Unit `()` syntax. The way I am trying to read it is 'we map a function which returns a function that takes no params and returns a Future[T] over the list of integers'. Is this correct? I'm always confused when I see multiple `=>` operators in a row..

Comment: I find this answer by @Daniel C. Sobral as the best explanation till date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit/4545703#4545703

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

It's parsed like this:

```
ns.map(_ => (() => block))
```

And the `() => ?` syntax is just defining a parameterless function:

```
val f = () => 1
f()  // 1
```

So the integer in `ns` is ignored, and you just get an iterator of functions that take no parameters and return Futures: `Iterator[() => Future[T]]`.

Comment: So is the => operator right associative then? (is it an operator?)

Answer (score 0):

I think this **block: => Future[T]** maybe the signature of the method. It means call-by-name. Basically, you can understand that it is just a type Future[T] which is lazy evaluated but not a function

```
val ns: Iterator[Int] = (1 to 3).iterator
ns.map(_ => () => block)
```

This will return Iterator[() => Future], so yes, you are right, this transform to a function which takes nothing to Future. The good thing of this is that it will not evaluate the Future immediately, it will be called when you invoked.

```
val result = ns.map(_ => () => block)

result.foreach(_())
```