# Scala shutdown hooks never running?

Tags: scala

The scaladoc for `sys.addShutdownHook` says `shutdown hooks are NOT guaranteed to be run`. Now this is entirely reasonable, as the JVM can hardly run shutdown hooks if you send the JVM a SIGKILL, or whatever the Windows equivalent is.

However shutdown hooks added with `sys.addShutdownHook` never seem to run, although those run with `Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook` do.

A test -

```
scala> val t = new Thread { override def run = println("hi!") }
t: java.lang.Thread = Thread[Thread-4,5,main]

scala> Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(t)

scala> hi!
george@george-MacBook:~$ scala
```

(Skipped the startup message)

```
scala> val t = new Thread { override def run = println("hi!") }
t: java.lang.Thread = Thread[Thread-4,5,main]

scala> sys.addShutdownHook(t.run _)
res0: scala.sys.ShutdownHookThread = Thread[shutdownHook1,5,main]

scala> george@george-MacBook:~$
```

The documentation says "The hook is automatically registered: the returned value can be ignored" so it's not that we're supposed to add the thread returned by `sys.addShutdownHook`
 (and at any rate that causes "IllegalArgumentException: Hook previously registered" to be thrown).

Also, calling run on thread returned by addShutdownHook doesn't seem to do anything, which is suspicious.

Comment: Are you using the Play framework? If so, you can use shutdown hooks.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Stopping/cleaning-up

Answer (score 26):

The type signature of `addShutdownHook` is ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/sys/package.scala#L74)):

```
def addShutdownHook(body: => Unit): ShutdownHookThread
```

So, it is obvious why your code is not working. Expected is a call-by-name argument `=> Unit` and you pass `t.run _`, which returns `() => Unit` - that is something entirely different.

Call-by-name parameters are not run until they are executed, passing `t.run _` to it means that a function is created at the time when the call-by-name argument is called - you are not passing the function itself instead of the call-by-name argument.

Use

```
sys.addShutdownHook(t.run)
```

instead. Or don't use the thread at all and just pass the code that should be executed:

```
sys.addShutdownHook(println("hi"))
```

Comment: What is the difference?

If you compile this scala `class Foo { def bar(a: => Unit) = (); def baz(a: () => Unit) = (); }` the jvm bytecode of both methods seem to be the same and both seem to use Function0

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit

Comment: @GeorgeSimms You also get bitten by value discarding (see e.g. http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/10/implicit-conversion-to-unit-type-in.html). Because of it, your shutdown hook actually says "create a function `t.run _` and throw it away".