# Play application lifecycle

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Recently I changed a Play application using Akka Actors to a classic Scala application. With Play, I override the global settings of the app like this :

```
import play.api._
import play.api.Play.current

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  var system: ActorSystem = _

override def onStart(app: Application) : Unit = {
    super.onStart(app)
    Logger.info("onStart")
    system = ActorSystem("SysActor")

override def onStop(app: Application) : Unit = {
    super.onStop(app)
    if (system != null) {
      system.terminate
      Logger.info(system + " shutdown !")
    }
  }
}
```

In a classic scala application, I defined a main class to be executed at `sbt run` command but is it a way to detect, like `Play Scala`, the close or stop of the running app ? Note that I published the app on Amazon EC2 using Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to register a shutdown hook, something like:

```
object MyApp {

  val system = ActorSystem("SysActor") // instantiation can be moved to main

  private val t = new Thread { 
    override def run() = {
      if (system != null) {
        system.terminate
        Logger.info(system + " shutdown !")
      }
    }        
  }

  Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(t)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { ... }

}
```

Shutdown hooks are called when the JVM gets a shutdown signal (although note that it's not [guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944515/scala-shutdown-hooks-never-running), depending on the signal)

Comment: So the call to `addShutdownHook` implicitly shutdown the actor system of my app ?

Comment: No, sorry - I wasn't clear - your implementation of the `run` method in the thread you're passing to `addShutdownHook` should do whatever needs to be done upon shutdown; In your case, it should call `system.terminate`

Comment: Or one line `sys.addShutdownHook(system.shutdown())` if `val system = ActorSystem(...)`