# How to compose a Function1 with Function0

Tags: scala

Given a `Function1` and a `Function0`,

```
val f = () => "toto"
val g = (s : String) => s.length
```

Is there a better way to compose them ?

```
val h : () => Int = () => g.apply(f())
```

Comment: Your last expression doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks good, I'd `.toString` the `length` for a string and use straight `g(...)` instead of `g.apply(...)`:

```
val f = () => "toto"
val g = (s: String) => s.length.toString
val h: () => String = () => g(f())
```

Comment: And with piping from scalaz : val h = () => f() |> g

Answer (score 1):

You can use compose:

```
val h: Unit => Int = {s: String => s.length} compose {_: Unit => "toto"}
```

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4545703/5020846) why you need to use `Unit => ` instead of `() =>`.

Comment: So if I need to compose with f, you suggest changing the type for Unit => String ?

Comment: The example is a little contrived, so I'm not really suggesting anything.  Peter's link is a very good exposition of the difference between () => A and Unit => A.  In SML compose would be the right thing to do, since there's not a distinction between the two cases.  I don't grok Scala well enough to advocate for some particular method.

Comment: val h = g compose f doesn't compile. So it's not an answer for me.