# Some questions about difference between call-by-name and 0-arity functions

Tags: scala

There are some discussions here about this, but I have some specific questions I wasn't able to find an answer for. So, by call-by-name, I mean `=>T` type, and by 0-arity function I mean `() => T`

I understand (I think) the conceptual difference, but probably I am missing something as I still have lots of questions:

1. Why do we have the concept of `=>T` at all if we could always use `() => T`?
2. Is there any syntax/functional limitations of each? For now I found only that `=>` cannnot be used as a class field. Is this the only limitation?
3. Is the generated code always the same for both?
4. Should I always prefer `=>T`? And why?
5. Is it correct to call `=>T` a type? It looks for me like it does not have any type representation in scala.

Comment: Consider this comment - https://twitter.com/StewOConnor/status/633555338894020608

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) It's just more handy to use it, especially inside DSLs:

```
def printAndGet[T](f: => T) = {
  val res = f
  println(res + " printed") 
  res
}

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val k = printAndGet {
  val a = 5
  5 * a 
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

25 printed
k: Int = 25
```

2) `=> T` can only be a parameter of method or function. And actually `=> T` and `() => T` aren't interchangable:

```
scala> def aaa(f: => String) = f
aaa: (f: => String)String

scala> val a: Function1[() => String, String] = aaa _
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (=> String) => String
 required: (() => String) => String
       val a: Function1[() => String, String] = aaa _
                                                ^
```

Thanks to @som-snytt, fоund this one:

```
scala> object O { def f(i: Int) = i; def f(i: => Int) = i + 1 }
defined object O

scala> O.f(5)
res12: Int = 5

scala> O.f(5: (=> Int))
<console>:1: error: no by-name parameter type allowed here
       O.f(5: (=> Int))
           ^
```

Even this which should work if it compiles - but it doesn't (scala 2.11.2, 2.11.5 REPL just crashes):

```
scala> val k: (=> Int) => Int = O.f _
k: (=> Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> k(5) //should be 6
res18: Int = 5 //WTF?
```

Last one seems like a bug

3) Not exactly, if you want the same, just convert `=> T` into `() => T`:

```
scala> def aaa(f: => String) = {f _}
aaa: (f: => String)() => String
```

Bytecode may also differ. For instance, compiler will more likely inline code from `=> T` without generating lambda for it. So, the key difference is that `() => T` is actually an object (first class citizen), `=> T` isn't.

4) see 1, but sometimes you may need to ensure that user knows that computation might be delayed - `() => T` is better then.

5) It's part of a type signature, just look at eta-expansion of:

```
scala> def aaa(f: => String) = {f}
aaa: (f: => String)String

scala> aaa _ //convert method into a function
res7: (=> String) => String = <function1>

scala> val a: ( => String) =>  String = aaa _
a: (=> String) => String = <function1>
```

However scala doesn't recognize it as independent type:

```
scala> val a: Function1[( => String), String] = aaa _
<console>:1: error: no by-name parameter type allowed here
       val a: Function1[( => String), String] = aaa _
                          ^
```

Comment: On #2, you can't use by-name type ascription, so for overloaded `f(i: Int)` and `f(i: => Int)`, you can't `f(0: => Int)`. Similar to your point about "independent" type.

Comment: 1) I understand that. I do not understand why do we need special `=>T` notation? We could always use `()=>T` and assume that any expression is of `()=>` type, rather than `=>T`.

Comment: 2) This doesn't seem true. I can at least use it as local val: `def aa(f:=>String) = { val g = f; println(g) }` then `aa { println("processed"); "return val" }`. I wonder what other usage of it can be

Comment: @Archeg 2) your local val gonna have just `T` type, not `=> T`, there is no way to produce clean `=> T` type

Comment: @Archeg 1) see 4. sometimes you may want to disallow that behavior. And see 3 - every parameter is gonna became an object then, meaning scala compiler will generate new class for it, `by-name` doesn't need a new generated class.

Comment: @som-snytt I actually expected compiler error on that code, seems like  a bug to me as there is no way (I didn't find) to call it, only override. Even if I do `val k: (=> Int) => Int = Object.f _` it still gives me a link to non-call-by-name function, which seems like a very bug.

Comment: See the first comment on https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3761 where I tried to tweak overload resolution.