# scala function literal confusion

Tags: scala, function-literal

I have made a unit test to study Scala function literal format and found it quite confusing, could you please help me understand meaning of different syntax?

```
@Test def supplierLiteral: Unit = {
    object Taker {

        def takeFunctionLiteral(supplier: => Int): Unit = {
            println("taker takes")
            //              println(supplier.apply()) //can't compile
            println(supplier)
        }

        def takeExplicitFunction0(supplier: () => Int): Unit = {
            println("taker takes")
            println(supplier())
        }
    }

    val give5: () => Int = () => {
        println("giver gives")
        5
    }


    println(give5.isInstanceOf[Function0[_]])

    Taker.takeFunctionLiteral(give5) //can't compile, expected Int
    println()
    Taker.takeExplicitFunction0(give5)
}
```

Why is `println(suppiler.apply())` incorrect syntax in `takeFunctionLiteral`?
Aren't both equivalent? What is the difference between

```
supplier: () => Int
```

and

```
supplier: => Int
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802104/some-questions-about-difference-between-call-by-name-and-0-arity-functions

Answer (score 0):

Here `supplier: () => Int` the type of the `supplier` is a `Function0[Int]`.
But here `supplier: => Int` the type of the `supplier` is an `Int`.

The difference between `supplier: => Int` (a) and `supplier: Int` (b) is that in case (a) supplier parameter is passed into function *by name* and will be evaluated only when accessed from inside function. In case (b) supplier parameter is evaluated on the line where function is called.