# What's the difference between `() =>` and `=>`?

Tags: scala

Say I write a method that takes in a function, and have another function that returns a function. I can write my method like so:

```scala
def logParens(f: () => String) = println(f())
```

Or like so:

```
def logNoParens(f: => String) = println(f)
```

And let's say I have a method that returns a string

```
def foo = "foo"
```

How come I can pass foo directly into `logNoParens`, but not `logParens`? Seems like Scala coerces `foo` into `=> foo` before passing it into `logNoParens`.

```
logParens(foo) // this gives me a type error
logParens(() => foo) // this compiles
logNoParens(foo) // this compiles just fine
```

What's the difference between `=>` and `() =>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit as referenced by the ambitious http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info

Comment: Add parens to `def foo()` to get eta expansion.

Comment: Thanks, @som-snytt. This type of question is pretty hard to google.

Comment: Yup. I haven't tried it, but the info page says To search for Scala symbols such as "=>" in Stack Overflow, you can use symbolhound search.

Answer (score 0):

in short: `() ⇒ String` creates a function of type `Unit ⇒ String` while `⇒ String` means **lazy** value of type `String` is passed as an argument, hence it is **not re-evaluated later in the function body, if referenced**.

So it will be **evaluated** only **once** when execution reaches it's reference in the code, and **not when passed as an argument**.

This form is very common for creation of high-order functions that accept somebody, like:

```
def func(f: ⇒ String) : Either[Exception, String]{
   if (someCondition) {
     Right(f)
   } else {
     Left(new IllegalArgumentException("F can't be evaluated")
   }
}
```

And the possible usage is:

```
def doF() {
  func {
    io.Stream.fromFile("path/to/file")
   }
}
```

ofcourse you could rewrite this as follows:

```
def func(f: () ⇒ String) : Either[Exception, String]{
  if (someCondition) {
     Right(f())
  } else {
     Left(new IllegalArgumentException("F can't be evaluated")
  }
}
```

And the possible usage is:

```
def doF() {
 func {
   case _ ⇒ io.Stream.fromFile("path/to/file")
  }
}
```

Depending on the context, you may choose former or latter form, those are completely interchangable in the cases described above. The only difference is that if you pass a **lazy** value to the function - it will be evaluated only **once**, but if you pass the function reference to the function - the function will be **executed** and the result of the evaluation **passed** to the function as many times as it is used in the function.

Comment: Seems like it's evaluated each time it's referenced within the function body.

    `def log(x: => Int) = 1 to 3 foreach { _ => println(x) };
    var z = 0;
    log { z = z + 1; z }`

This example logs 1, 2, 3