# Scala : Why should i save a by-name parameter as a Function0

Tags: scala, pass-by-name

I am working through a coursera example of `Signal` and cannot make sense of this syntax,

```
class Signal[T](expr: => T) {
 import Signal._
 private var myExpr: () => T = _
 private var myValue: T = _
 private var observers: Set[Signal[_]] = Set()
 private var observed: List[Signal[_]] = Nil
 update(expr)
```

The update method is written as

```
    protected def update(expr: => T): Unit = {
    myExpr = () => expr
    computeValue()
  }
```

I can understand that `expr` is being passed by name so is evaluated only when called. 
But what i cannot get my head around is why is the `myExpr` represented as `() => T` ?
Also why is the assignment written as `myExpr = () => expr` . From what i understand `() => expr` denotes a Function0 that returns `expr`.
I think my understanding of `byname` is wrong. Can someone please elaborate on this ?

Or can we rewrite the above syntax as follows,

```
  class Signal[T](expr: () => T) {
  import Signal._
  private var myExpr: () => T = _
  private var myValue: T = _
  private var observers: Set[Signal[_]] = Set()
  private var observed: List[Signal[_]] = Nil
  update(expr)
```

And the update method as ,

```
 protected def update(expr: () => T): Unit = {
    myExpr = expr
    computeValue()
  }
```

Comment: After `myExpr = () => expr`, if `myExpr` is ever invoked via `myExpr()`, then `expr` will, at long last, after all this time, finally be evaluated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between => , ()=>, and Unit=>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr: => T
```

as function argument stands for *call-by-name* that is not only delayed evaluation (aka lazy) but also that it is evaluated each time it is accessed.

```
private var myExpr: () => T = _
```

Indicates that it is a variable of type `() => T` which means that it takes no arguments and returns `T`. If you put `expr: () => T` as function argument it makes an argument of type `() => T` which, again, means it takes no arguments and returns `T`, which is NOT a *call-by-name*.
These two things are slightly confusing because of syntax similarities but are quite different.

You could use it like this:

```
myExpr = () => 4
myExpr() //evaluates as 4
```

Whereas calling `myExpr()` without assigning `() => 4` to it would throw `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

In the coursera course Odersky explaines very well what is a *call-by-name* evaluation with his `def loop: Unit = loop` example.

Comment: i want to understand why is the assignment `myExpr = () => expr` in the update method. Does it mean i accept a by-name parameter `expr` and save it to myExpr as a "() => expr" ?   In other words why would i save a by-name parameter as a function ?

Comment: Let's simplify the *by-name*. The way it differs from *by-value* is the way it is evaluated. So, `expr: => T` upon access will evaluate to T and will be no different from `expr: T` which will be evaluated upon the function call. `myExpr = () => expr` is in the update method because `expr: => T` is in the constructor and it might be a very long computation that you don't want to evaluate upon instantiation of the object. Nextly, yes, it does mean that you save it to `myExpr` as you said and you want it for the reason mentioned one sentence above.