# What does "double right-arrow Type" with no LHS mean in function argument

Tags: scala

I am having trouble interpreting "double-rightarrow Type" specified as a function argument without a LHS (left hand side) e.g. `() => Int` is from `()` to `Int` but what does just `=> Int` mean?
e.g. see the first argument of `foo` method below, what is the type of `f`? Is it `(Int, () => Int) => Int`?

For the definition of `bar`, where y is passed by name, I've interpreted it as a function with no argument that will produce an Int, which looks equivalent to definition of `baz`.

I could try to reason that `f` in `foo` takes the second argument as call by name, and is not from `() => Int` but that is contradicting that fact that `bar` and `baz` definitions are identical in javap. What am I missing?

```
object ParamTest {
  def foo(f: (Int, => Int) => Int, x: Int) : Int = 10
  def bar(x: Int, y: => Int) : Int = 20
  def baz(x: Int, f: () => Int) : Int = 30
  def qux(f: (Int, () => Int) => Int, x: Int) : Int = 40
}
```

For testing I compiled the above class with `scalac ParamTest.scala`

`javap ParamTest` gives me:

```
public final class ParamTest {
  public static int qux(scala.Function2<java.lang.Object, scala.Function0<java.lang.Object>, java.lang.Object>, int);
  public static int baz(int, scala.Function0<java.lang.Object>);
  public static int bar(int, scala.Function0<java.lang.Object>);
  public static int foo(scala.Function2<java.lang.Object, scala.Function0<java.lang.Object>, java.lang.Object>, int);
}
```

That seems to indicate that foo and qux have the same method signature. In other words, I could interpret `=> Int` as `() => Int`, but
`foo(baz,100)` gives me a type mismatch error

```
scala> import ParamTest._
import ParamTest._

scala> foo(bar,100)
res0: Int = 10

scala> foo(baz,100)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, () => Int) => Int
 required: (Int, => Int) => Int
              foo(baz,100)
                  ^
```

**EDIT**: This is not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit). I'm not asking the practical difference between `call-by-name: => Type` and `() => Type`. What I'm more interesting in knowing is the internals. How does scala differentiate between the two, when javap or [cfr decompilation](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/) gives me identical definitions for `foo` and `qux`; and for `bar` and `baz`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've discovered, `() => A` and `=> A` are not the same thing.

Call by name (i.e. `=> A`) simply means: "delay the evaluation of this method argument."  In other words, lazy evaluation.

```
def f(x: Int, y: => Int) = ???

f(3+5, 2+4)
```

In this example the addition of 3+5 is done at the call site and the `x` value is 8. The addition of 2+4, on the other hand, isn't done until `y` is referenced inside the body of the method `f()`.  If that reference is in an `if...else...` branch that doesn't get executed then the addition is never done.

This is pretty pointless for simple evaluations like `Int` addition, but it becomes more meaningful if the argument is an expensive evaluation, of if it's a block of code with side effects.

So, in answer to your question, the meaning of `f: (Int, => Int) => Int` is: "`f` takes two arguments and produces an `Int`, the arguments are 2 `Int`s, the 2nd of which is evaluated lazily."

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the explanation. Do you know where I can find more details about this in Scala spec? I tried to work through [Section 4.6](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html) but am unable to derive the argument without a LHS for the by-name parameter :(, but at least my confusion is cleared, so I can move ahead.

Comment: Well, I don't know the Scala spec, but there are other ways to get this information.  As has been pointed out, searching SO for questions that have already been asked is a good place to start. Also, the book "Programming in Scala" (1st edition) is available [online](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/). Beyond that there are numerous blog posts.  Plug a few terms into a search engine and bookmark sites that are useful.

Comment: I have read end-to-end [this tutorial](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) by Martin Odersky and also finished his first two courses on Coursera. What I wanted to know is how is Scala distinguishing between the two types `() => A` and `=> A` when decompiling the class file gives me `Function0` in both cases. But this question wasn't clear enough, so I'll ask a new one. You definitely helped with the lazy evaluation part.