# Unable to understand Scala's type inference

Tags: scala

I was going through **Learning Concurrency With Scala**
It had a following piece of Code.

```
package week_parallel.week1.SC_Book

import scala.collection.mutable

object SyncPoolArgs extends App {
  private val tasks = mutable.Queue[() => Unit]()
  object Worker extends Thread {
    setDaemon(true)
    def poll() = tasks.synchronized {
      while (tasks.isEmpty) tasks.wait()
      tasks.dequeue()
    }
    override def run() = while (true) {
      val task = poll()
      task()
    }
  }
  Worker.start()
  def asynchronous(body: =>Unit) = tasks.synchronized {
    tasks.enqueue(() => body)
    tasks.notify()
  }

  def sum(x: Int, y:Int) = {println("USING SUM")
    x+y}

  asynchronous { log("Hello ") }
  asynchronous { log("World!") }
  asynchronous { sum(4,5) }
  Thread.sleep(500)
}
```

So, my question is if we have tasks of type function that takes no arguments and returns nothing, why does `tasks.enqueue(() => body)` put sum in the queue, shouldn't it check that the body method signature is wrong in case of sum.

Also, I am particularly unable to grasp how does `tasks.enqueue(() => body)` confine to the `private val tasks = mutable.Queue[() => Unit]()` type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between => , ()=>, and Unit=>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543228/whats-the-difference-between-and-unit)

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be confused by the declaration

```
body: => Unit
```

This means that `body` is a [pass-by-name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_name) parameter of type `Unit`. This does **not** mean that `body` is a function that returns `Unit`, which would be `body: () => Unit`.

"pass by name" means that the expression that is passed to `body` will not be evaluated until the value is required. When it is evaluated, it will return `Unit`.

Since `body` is of type `Unit`, the expression `() => body` has type `() => Unit` which is what is required.

In this case the actual value of `body` is `sum(4,5)` which is type `Int`, but `Int` is compatible with `Unit` so there is no error.

Comment: pass-by-value param or pass-by-name?

Comment: It's pass-by-name.

Comment: Many apologies for my error, it is, of course, "pass by name". Thanks to @DmytroMitin for fixing my error.

Comment: @DmytroMitin, I was checking Alvin's tutorial https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/how-to-use-by-name-parameters-scala-functions
In which he defines following
def timer(blockOfCode: => theReturnType), That indicates the return type..
Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Tim, I was checking Alvin's tutorial https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/how-to-use-by-name-parameters-scala-functions
In which he defines following
def timer(blockOfCode: => theReturnType), That indicates the return type..
Any ideas on that?

Comment: @IshanBhatt What is your question?

Comment: In the answer as @Tim points out body:=>Unit , body is type of Unit, but in the post by alvin it looks like blockOfCode(body) is something that returns theReturnType. So which one is true?

Comment: @IshanBhatt You can call type as you want `def timer(blockOfCode: => BlaBlaType)`. In some sense types `=> A`, `() => A`, `Unit => A` are similar. Inside method `def foo(body: => A)` `body` is of type `A`, inside method `def bar(body: () => A)` `body()` is of type `A`, inside method `def baz(body: Unit => A)` `body(())` is of type `A`. But in type system of Scala types `=> A` (by-name parameter of type `A`), `() => A` (function of zero arguments to type `A`), `Unit => A` (function of single argument of type `Unit` to `A`) are different.

Comment: In languages without by-name (lazy) calculations (like Javascript) lambdas is way 'for poors' to emulate those.