# Why "case class" doesn't need "new" to create a new object

Tags: class, scala, case

In Scala what is the reason that you don't need to use "new" to create a new "case class"?
I tried searching for awhile now without answers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Do you want the *how* or the *why*? As the other answer notes, the *how* is just the `apply` method on the automatically generated companion object.

For the *why*: case classes are often used to implement [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) in Scala, and the `new`-less constructor allows code that is more elegant (creating a value looks more like deconstructing it via pattern matching, for example) and that more closely resembles ADT syntax in other languages.

Answer (score 15):

Case class has prebuilt companion object with `apply()` implemented. Someone even complains about this: [How to override apply in a case class companion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827510/how-to-override-apply-in-a-case-class-companion) :)

Answer (score 8):

Case classes provide you with an **automatically generated** `apply` function on their companion object that you can use like a constructor.

In **Scala** decompiled byte code you will find `apply` function created as the following :

```
object Person {
def apply(name: String, age: Integer): Person = new Person(name,age)
}
```

**Example :**

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Integer)
```

The following three all do the same thing.

```
val p0 = new Person("Frank", 23) // normal constructor

val p1 = Person("Frank", 23) // this uses apply

val p2 = Person.apply("Frank", 23) // using apply manually
```

So if you use `val p1 = Person("Frank", 23)` **it is not a constructor**, this a method that call apply method.

Please read [scala-object-apply-functions](https://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2017/03/06/scala-object-apply-functions.html) for more info.