# Importing Functions from Other Classes in Scala

Tags: function, class, scala, import

Say for example I have

```
class foo{
  def bar = 7
}

class qaz{
  //Here I want to have something like: val foobar = bar
  //What I don't want to have is val foobar = (new foo).bar   
}
```

How canI achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the companion object of `foo` to define `bar`.

Then you can simply import it in `qaz`:

```
// in foo.scala
object foo {
  def bar = 7
}
class foo {
  // whatever for foo class
}

// in qaz.scala
import mypackage.foo.bar
class qaz {
  val foobar = bar     // it works!
}
```

Comment: For this to work, foo would need to be the companion object of foo.scala ? Can I have a companion class as well?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Using a Companion Object
2. [Case Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777199/why-case-class-doesnt-need-new-to-create-a-new-object)

The second method, i.e. method requiring the inclusion of a companion object, as already implemented by Jean :

```
class foo {
// whatever for foo class
}

//Companion Object
object foo {
    def bar = 7
}

class qaz {
  val foobar = bar 
}
```

By creating a case class instead of a normal class, a lot of boilerplate code is created for you, one of which is generation of an apply method, so you don’t need to use the new keyword to create a new instance of the class.

```
case class foo{
  def bar = 7
}

class qaz{
   val foobar = bar  
}
```

Both of these approaches are sort of syntactic sugar but doing the same thing in the back, that is, using an apply function in a companion object.
Try [this](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-scala-object-instances-without-new-apply-case-class) for more information.

Comment: Which part are referring to, specifically ?

Comment: `case class foo { ... }` (in the second case, unless using a very old Scala version) and `val foobar = bar` (in both cases).