# Why do I have to pass new keyword?

Tags: scala, akka, new-operator

I have the following code:

```
val fsm = TestFSMRef(new SenderCollectorFsm)
```

And do not understand, why do I have to pass to `TestFSMRef` an instance.

Lets look at the definition of [**TestFSMRef**](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.23/akka-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/testkit/TestFSMRef.scala):

```
object TestFSMRef {

  def apply[S, D, T <: Actor: ClassTag](
      factory: => T)(implicit ev: T <:< FSM[S, D], system: ActorSystem): TestFSMRef[S, D, T] = {
    val impl = system.asInstanceOf[ActorSystemImpl]
    new TestFSMRef(impl, Props(factory), impl.guardian.asInstanceOf[InternalActorRef], TestActorRef.randomName)
  }
```

`T` is subtype of `Actor` and `ClassTag`, but how to know, that `T` has to be an object?

Comment: Are you wondering why `new` has to be used instead of `TestFSMRef(SenderCollectorFsm)` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sometimes scala is weired.

Comment: Please show definition of `SenderCollectorFsm`.

Comment: `SenderCollectorFsm` is an actor of https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fsm.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala is an object-oriented language. Like in almost all object-oriented languages, you can only pass objects as arguments. Also, like most languages, types aren't objects.

So, since you can only pass objects, and types aren't objects, it is clear that you can only pass an instance.

Or, to be more precise: there exist two separate universes, the universe of *types* and the universe of *values*. In the universe of values, we have methods which take values as arguments in round parentheses (or occasionally curly braces).

In the universe of types, we have type constructors, which take types as arguments in square brackets.

There is exactly one place where the two universes meet, and that is in path-dependent types.

Answer (score 3):

If `SenderCollectorFsm` is defined as a regular class like so

```
class SenderCollectorFsm(...
```

then we have to use `new`, however if it was defined as case class like so

```
case class SenderCollectorFsm(...
```

then we could write `TestFSMRef(SenderCollectorFsm)`.

However in both cases we are passing a *value* not a *type*, as Jörg W Mittag explained. Although I can see how `TestFSMRef(SenderCollectorFsm)` might appear as if we are passing a type, it is simply a shorthand for passing an instance of a case class. Refer to [Why "case class" doesn't need "new" to create a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777199/why-case-class-doesnt-need-new-to-create-a-new-object)

Also note that `T` is not a subtype of `ClassTag`, since [type parameter clause](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#type-parameters)

```
T <: Actor : ClassTag
```

consists of two distinct type constraints on `T`

```
T <: Actor
T : ClassTag
```

where `T <: Actor` indeed specifies `T` is a subtype of `Actor`, however `T : ClassTag` specifies `T` has to have an implicit type class `ClassTag[T]` in scope. Note the difference between type constraints `<:` and `:`, where former is an *upper bound*, whilst latter is a *context bound*.