# Algebraic types that can be instantiated via a sentinel function only

Tags: scala, static-typing

I'd like to use case classes to describe the types of my data more expressively so that to benefit from higher static correctness. The goal is to have 100% static certainty that any `Age` value in existence always contains a valid human age (leaving aside the fact that encapsulation rules can be bypassed using reflection).

For example, instead of using `Int` to store ages of persons, I have:

```
case class Age(x: Int) extends AnyVal
def mkAge(x: Int) = if (0 <= x && x <= 150) Some(Age(x)) else None
def unwrapAge(age: Age) = age.x
```

however, this implementation suffers from the fact that `Age` can still be instantiated without going through `mkAge` and `unwrapAge`.

Next, I tried to make the constructor private:

```
case class Age private(x: Int) extends AnyVal
object Age {
  def make(x: Int) = if (0 <= x && x <= 150) Some(Age(x)) else None
  def unwrap(age: Age) = age.x
}
```

however, while this *does* prevent `Age` from being instantiated using new (e.g. `new Age(3)`), the autogenerated `apply(x: Int)` in `object Age` is still easily accessible.

So, here's the question: how to hide both the constructor as well as the default `apply` method in the companion object from anything but `Age.make` or `mkAge`?

I'd like to avoid having to use a regular (non-`case`) class and correctly replicate the auto-generated methods in `class Age` and `object Age` manually.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
case class Age private(private val x:Int) extends AnyVal
object Age {
  def mkAge(x:Int) = if(0<=x && x<=150) Some(Age(x)) else None
  def unwrapAge(age:Age) = age.x
}
```

Note the extra `private val` inside the case class constructor.

Comment: This doesn't compile in 2.10.3 at least: "error: value class needs to have a publicly accessible val parameter". And even if it did, it wouldn't help.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Sorry, then it's not possible with 2.10. I compiled it with 2.11. It does reach your goal: Neither the constructor nor the companion object's apply method can be called from the outside, and x is also not publicly accessible. In which way doesn't it help?

Comment: "nor the companion object's apply method can be called from the outside" Then this is a Scala bug, since `Age.apply` visibility shouldn't depend on `x`'s. According to http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes, it's always public.

Comment: `x` is not accessible, but this isn't asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> So, here's the question: how to hide both the constructor as well as the default apply method in the companion object from anything but Age.make or mkAge?
>
> I'd like to avoid having to use a regular (non-case) class and correctly replicate the auto-generated methods in class Age and object Age manually.

I thought it was impossible, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/25538287/9204 details a (rather non-trivial) solution.

Comment: There are some problems with that solution: A) It's very complex, as you mentioned. B) It produces a warning, as extending case classes is discouraged and might be forbidden in a future Scala version. C) You won't get the case class benefits without rewriting them yourself, which was a requirement. D) I'm not sure if it's even possible to have an abstract value class, and even when, the instances will be likely to be boxed most of the time anyway.

Comment: @Madoc C) What benefits do you lose? All methods are still generated and inherited by the anonymous class. The only one you have to rewrite is `copy` and I don't think you can work around that. D) Yes, you lose value class; if it's a requirement, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think Age just don't need to be a case class. Because it is a Value Class you don't need  to override equals and hashcode, also it has only one field so there is no benefit from copy constructor. And you can do nothing with *apply()* in companion object. If you still want to use case class you can add *require* but it doesn't solve you problem of instantiation.

```
object A extends App {

  import Age._

  println(mkAge(150))
  println(mkAge(151))
  //println(new Age(51))   //Error!


  val a = mkAge(15) match {
    case Some(Age(x)) => x
    case None => 0
  }

  print(a)
}

class Age private(val x: Int) extends AnyVal {
  override def toString = s"A($x)"
}

object Age {
  def mkAge(x: Int) = if (0 <= x && x <= 150) Some(new Age(x)) else None
  def unwrapAge(age: Age) = age.x
  def unapply(age: Age) = if (age == null) None else Some(age.x)
}
```

Comment: if it's a value type, it does need equals and hashcode; also, the fact of it having just one field is arbitrary — it might well have 10 fields.

Comment: It will no longer be a Value Class with more than 1 field. So for Value Classes to be also a case class isn't an advantage, I think. Is being a Value Class important?

Comment: I didn't say AnyVal — value types are a general term. AnyVal is just an optimisation.