# In scala, is it possible to have a two-elements only Set?

Tags: scala

In the end, I want to have a **case class Swap** so that **Swap(a, b) == Swap(b, a)**.

I thought I could use a Set of two elements, and it quite does the job :

```
scala> case class Swap(val s:Set[Int])
defined class Swap

scala> Swap(Set(2, 1)) == Swap(Set(1, 2))
res0: Boolean = true
```

But this allows for any number of elements, and I would like to **limit my elements to two**. I found the class Set.Set2, which is the default implementation for an immutable Set with two elements, but it doesn't work the way I tried, or variations of it :

```
scala> val a = Set(2, 1)
a: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 1)

scala> a.getClass
res3: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set2

scala> case class Swap(val s:Set.Set2[Int])
defined class Swap

scala> val swp = Swap(a)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]
 required: Set.Set2[Int]
       val swp = Swap(a)
                      ^
```

So my questions are :

- is there a way to use Set2 as I try ?
- is there a better way to implement my case class Swap ? I read that one shouldn't override equals in a case class, though it was my first idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generic implementation -

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Set.Set2

def set2[T](a: T, b: T): Set2[T] = Set(a, b).asInstanceOf[Set2[T]]

case class Swap[T](s: Set2[T])

Swap(set2(1,2))  == Swap(set2(2,1)) //true
```

The reason that your solution didn't work is because of the signature

```
Set(elems: A*): Set
```

In case of 2 elements the concrete type will be Set2 but the compiler doesn't know that so you have to cast it to Set2

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I used. I also added a second contructor `def this(t1: T, t2: T) = this(Set(t1, t2).asInstanceOf[Set2[T]])` for convenience, which allowed me to construct swaps with `new Swap(t1, t2)`.

Finally I used pattern matching this way : 
`case Swap(s:Set2[T]) => {
            val t1 = s.head
            val t2 = s.last
... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can always *hide the implementation details of `Swap`*, in this case you actually *should*.

You could implement it using `Set` or you could implement it as:

```
 // invariant a <= b
 class Swap private (val a: Int, val b: Int)

 object Swap {
   def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Swap =
     if (a <= b) new Swap(a, b) else new Swap(b, a)
 }
```

Unfortunately you have to use `class` here and reimplement `equals` `hashCode` etc yourself, as we cannot get rid of `scalac` auto-generated `apply`: [related SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827510/how-to-override-apply-in-a-case-class-companion)

And make all functions on `Swap` maintain that invariant.

Then equals comparion is essentially `this.a == other.a && this.b == other.b`, we don't need to care about swapping anymore.

Comment: I would add the override for equals in order to get the result @Guillaume expects. Also, it would be very useful to define some extractor, that way the equality will also work nice on pattern matching

Comment: The point of keeping invariant, and not-allowing constructing invalid objects makes structural equality behave as we want.

Comment: It doesn't seem to compile : error: constructor Swap in class Swap cannot be accessed in object Swap. And most of all, this is not a case class anymore, and therefore doesn't really answer the question. But thank you anyway !

Comment: @phadej while what you say is true, since you leverage on the elements being Ints, but they could be of any generic type (as per the question asked, where the Ints were merely examples), the part  `a <= b would't work`

Comment: The OP uses Int as example, so I use it too. AFAIK set uses `hashCode` to order the elements, so can be used here - the change is minimal.

Comment: @GuillaumeDeshors create `Swap` object with `Swap(1,2)` not with `new Swap(1,2)`. *case classes* are normal classes, for which `scalac` generates bunch of useful stuff - no more no less. In this case, we don't really like default `apply` though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't know statically that `a` is a `Set2` - as far as the compiler is concerned you called `Set(as: A*)` and got back some kind of `Set`.

You could use [shapeless sized collections](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#collections-with-statically-known-sizes) to enforce a statically known collection size.

Comment: Yes I called `Set(as: A*)` because I couldn't find a way to construct directly a `Set2`...

Comment: Yeah, the constructor is `private[collections]`. You could invoke it by reflection, or perhaps more usefully you could pattern-match: `a match { case s2: Set2 => Swap(s2) }`. But this is not entirely safe; if `a` isn't a `Set2` it will throw a `MatchError` at runtime.