# When to use companion object factory versus the new keyword

Tags: scala, conventions, companion-object

Many classes in the Scala standard library use `apply()` of their companion object as factory. This is often convenient when chaining calls like `List(List(1))`. On the other hand, it's still possible to create objects directly with `new` (`new HashMap[Int, Int]()`).

That's standard library. Now, in my own code, which approach is better to use: companion factory or creating objects with `new`?

Is there any convention on when to create companion object factory and when to do with the `new` keyword?

What are the advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: Because using `new` is like wearing a top hat or suspenders. It's stylish for a certain style, but not very contemporary. The companion factory is a pair of casual fit jeans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases I use the companion object's `apply` method, because the code looks less cluttered. However, there is at least one benefit of using a static factory. Consider the unimaginative type `MyInt` which just wraps an `Int`:

```
class MyInt(val i: Int)
```

I can obtain instances of `MyInt` calling the constructor which will instantiate a new object each time the constructor is called. If my program relies heavy on `MyInt` this results in a lot of instances created. Assuming most of the `MyInt` I use  are `-1`, `0`, and `1`, since `MyInt` is immutable I can reuse the same instances:

```
class MyInt(val i: Int) 

object MyInt {
  val one = new MyInt(1)
  val zero = new MyInt(0)
  val minusOne = new MyInt(-1)

  def apply(i: Int) = i match {
    case -1 => minusOne
    case 0 => zero
    case 1 => one
    case _ => new MyInt(i)
  }
}
```

So at least for immutable values there can be a technical advantage of using the static factory over calling the constructor. As an implication, if you want to express in code that a new instance is created, then use the `new` keyword. Personally, I use the `new`-keyword when creating objects, and the `apply`-method when creating values, though I don't know if there is an official convention.

Comment: I like the idea with value caching. The lesson learned is that you can easily change the implementation of apply() to do whatever you want but when you use `new`, you must always end up with a new instance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there is a general recommendation of one approach over the other, usually it is just a convenience not to have to type `new`.

There are occasions, though, where the factory method option can be better. For example, if your class has a String field that must be uppercase, you can make the standard constructor private, forcing instantiation via the factory method which ensures the field is always uppercase:

```
class A private[A] (s: String)

object A {
    def apply(s: String): A = new A(s.toUpperCase)
}
```

Note: if your class is a case class, there are a couple of other tweaks to get this to work fully - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236594/case-class-private-constructor-need-for-readresolve-implementation).

Comment: As an impl detail, `private[A]` results in a public ctor. More usual just to `private` since it means the same to Scala but has a private ctor for Java.

Comment: I don't have that much experience with Scala, but doesn't it become bothersome having to write the extra companion for every object?

Comment: @Mifeet Case classes provide a (usually) suitable companion object for free, so generally it isn't a bother at all.

Comment: Yup, but I wouldn't want a case class for a service with several dependencies. Perhaps we could draw the line between implementation classes wired by DI management (`new`), and other classes dynamically created after startup (factory)?

Comment: Sure, sounds like a reasonable division. I'd say whatever feels right for a given project/team.