# Using New Keyword inside apply method in a companion object

Tags: scala, case-class, companion-object

I am a little bit confused using companion objects in scala. When you want to provide multiple constructors, usually you declare a companion object and overload the `apply` method. But what is the difference between this two ways of doing it?:

```
case class Node(....)

object Node {
   def apply(...) = new Node(....) // 1 way
   def apply(...) = Node(...) // second way
}
```

Almost all examples I've seen use the first form:

- [When to use companion object factory versus the new keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279539/when-to-use-companion-object-factory-versus-the-new-keyword)
- ["new" keyword in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727637/new-keyword-in-scala)
- http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-scala-object-instances-without-new-apply-case-class

But my code seems to work the same using both forms. Does using `new` keyword only have sense when we have a normal  class? (Not a case class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
val n = Node(..)
```

The compiler will expand the code to a `Node.apply` call. Now, one of these `apply` methods will internally *have to* call `new` in order to create an instance of the type. Case classes provide companion objects with an `apply` method for you out of the box to allow the shorter syntax.

> When you want to provide multiple constructors, usually you declare a companion object and overload the apply method

This is the case for case classes. You can also provide additional auxiliary constructors using `this()`:

```
class Foo(i: Int) {
  def this() {
    this(0)
  }
}
```

Note this will not provide the syntax sugar `apply` does, you'll need to use `new`.

Comment: So, when I have a case class in which I overload `apply`, it is better to create the object inside `apply` using `new`, isn't?

Comment: It's not better. You are free to use the provided `apply` if you want. It will internally call `new` to create the instance. Choose whichever you feel like, just make sure you don't recursively call your own `apply`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a case class. A companion object is generated by the compiler with apply method in it whose implementation creates the object of the case class using new keyword.

So you need not create a companion object again with apply method creating object of the case class using new keyword. This work will be done by the compiler