# How to refer to "this" in an implicit method

Tags: scala, implicit

Given a case class and companion object like below:

```
case class Example(a: String)

object Example {
  implicit def concat(b: String): Example =
    Example(this.a + b)
}
```

How to make the implicit method compile? In other words, is it possible to refer to the current instance that the implicit method has been called upon?

Comment: `concat` cannot be called upon an instance of `Example`. As a result there is no instance in scope for `this` to refer to.

Comment: There is already something similar asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528736/case-class-and-companion-object

Comment: @amer, it's similar but doesn't quite answer my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is the following:

```
object Foo {
  implicit class RichExample(val e: Example) {
    def concat(b: String): Example = Example(e.a + b)
  }
}
```

or using an anonymous implicit class

```
object Foo {
  implicit def richExample(e: Example) = new {
    def concat(b: String): Example = Example(e.a + b)
  }
}
```

### Usage

You can then use it like this

```
import Foo._

Example("foo").concat("bar")
```

### Import and companion object

If the object is called `Example`, then it becomes the companion object for class `Example`, and you do not have to `import Foo._` to use the extension method.

Comment: How do I call it though? Compiler doesn't allow me to do `Example("a").concat("b")`

Comment: Ok, the outer singleton should be called like the case class, then it works. Thanks! :)

Comment: Or add `import Foo.RichExample`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, yes, but then the code becomes a bit more cluttered.