# How abstract class works in Scala?

Tags: scala, class, spark-graphx, companion-object

I'm new to scala and working with GraphX api. Here I'm trying to create Graph using below code snippet

`val graph = Graph(verticesRDD, edgesRDD).cache()`

`Graph` is abstract class in `org.apache.spark.graphx` package, since its a abstract class we can not have its constructor.

Above code snippet must be calling `Graph` concrete class constructor.  So In same abstract class, I found `Graph` object under which I found `apply`  method and when I use like  `Graph.apply(verticesRDD, edgesRDD).cache()`, its produce same output like `Graph(verticesRDD, edgesRDD).cache()`

So my doubts are, How come `apply` method in  `Graph object` is related to `Graph` abstract class. I'm confused here, Can anyone help me to understand this ?

Which constructor of `Graph`  abstract class is being called here ? Is `apply`   method is being called as constructor or something else ?

Thanks

trying to understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806029/scala-companion-object-purpose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36528736/case-class-and-companion-object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286750/class-companion-object-vs-case-class-itself/

Comment: @DmytroMitin, companion object is a object of Anonymous class which is implementing abstract class and can have multiple constructors with diff name, Is it correct ? But in java we should have constructors with same name only..Makes sense ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/what-is-the-apply-function-in-scala

Comment: *"companion object is a object of Anonymous class"* No. A class and its companion object are two different classes. You can have as many methods as you want both in a class and in its companion (as many constructors as you want in the class). The `apply` method of companion is a factory method (using design-pattern terminology).

Comment: @DmytroMitin, but we cannot create constructors for abstract class, so whenever I'll try to create instance of abstract class, it will ultimately look to its companion object methods (constructor)..right ? If not, so you mean abstract class and its companion object not related to each other at all ?

Comment: Did you read the questions linked?

Comment: yes, but still confused

Comment: *"whenever I'll try to create instance of abstract class"* If the class is abstract you can't create its instance, only instances of its subclasses. *"it will ultimately look to its companion object methods (constructor)..right?"* No. *"abstract class and its companion object not related to each other at all"* Right. Just a class and its companion can see private members of each other (and also companion objects play special role in implicit resolution).

Comment: A regular class and its companion define 2 distinct runtime classes and 2 distinct types. Their relation is that they both can see each others private methods/fields/constructors etc BUT companion is a singleton in runtime and, for Java compatibility, its methods would become available as regular classes `static` methods for Java. Implicits containing class in their type will also be sought in classes companion. Companion will have an instance in runtime - normally from a different type hierarchy than an accompanied class. If that class is abstract... only its subtypes could have instances.