# Scala pattern matching with combinations over parameter list

Tags: scala, parameters, pattern-matching

I have a case class `Pair(a: Int, b: Int)`, which represents a pair of 2 integers. In order to have `Pair(2, 5) == Pair(5, 2)`, I overrided the `equals` method as follows.

```
override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
  case Corner(c, d) => (a == c && b == d) || (a == d && b == c)
  case _ => false
}
```

Now the equality holds true, `Pair(2, 5) == Pair(5, 2)` returns true, like I wanted. However, this does not work when pattern matching:

```
Pair(2, 5) match {
  case Pair(5, 2) => print("This is what I want")
  case _ => print("But this is what I get")
}
```

Could anyone please assist me? Can/should I even do it this way? What are the alternatives? I really don't want to write `case Pair(2, 5) | case(5, 2) =>` every time I pattern match with pairs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538287/4541415 This answer to a related question is what I ended up using – I highly reccomend anyone looks at this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a good solution for this case may be not to override `equals`, but to disallow unordered pairs instead:

```
case class Pair(a: Int, b: Int) {
  assert(a <= b, s"First parameter of Pair($a, $b) must be less or equal to the second")
}

object Pair {
  def of(a: Int, b: Int) = if (a <= b) Pair(a, b) else Pair(b, a)
}
```

Quite unfortunately, Scala doesn't allow "overriding" the `apply` method in the companion object of a case class, otherwise this would be a very transparent solution.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:**
That just won't work. You could rework your statement like this though:

```
Pair(2, 5) match {
  case that if that == Pair(5, 2) => println("This is what I want")
  case _ => println("nope")
}
```

**Long answer:**
When you `match` on a case class, it's not using `equals`; it's actually using the companion object's `unapply` method. In fact a large majority of the "magic" behind scala's `match/case` statements boils down to `unapply`.

When you write `case class Pair(a: Int, b: Int)`, you get a lot of things for free. One of them is [an extractor](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/extractor-objects.html), e.g.:

```
object Pair {
  def unapply(pair: Pair): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
    Some((pair.a, pair.b))
  }
}
```

So when you say `pair match { case Pair(a, b) => ... }`, the compiler thinks `Pair.unapply(pair)`, then assigns `a` to the value in the `_1` position of the resulting tuple, and assigns `b` to the value in the `_2` position. (If `Pair.unapply(pair)` returned `None`, that case would fail).

Essentially, you can only get one particular value per input from an extractor, but what you are looking for would require two.

Answer (score 0):

As [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064342/4541415) stated, it is not possible to override the unapply method of case classes. In my case, however, I don't necessarilly need `Pair` to be a case class, so first I did this:

```
class Pair(val a: Int, val b: Int)
object Pair {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = new Pair(a, b)

  def unapply(arg: Pair): Option[(Int, Int)] = {
    if (arg.a < arg.b)
      Some(arg.a, arg.b)
    else
      Some(arg.b, arg.a)
  }
}

Pair(5, 2) match {
  case Pair(3, 4) => "It's dumb"
  case Pair (2, 5) => "Matched!"
  case _ => "Doesn't work"
}

Pair(2, 5) match {
  case Pair(3, 4) => "It's dumb"
  case Pair (2, 5) => "Matched!"
  case _ => "Doesn't work"
}

Pair(2, 5) match {
  case Pair(4, 3) => "It's dumb"
  case Pair(5, 2) => "Doesn't match!"
  case _ => "Should have written the digits in ascending order!"
}
```

As can be seen, it's not perfect – I still have to make sure to write my match cases with the digits in ascending order. However, once I realised that by simply asserting that the values are ordered in the constructor, I can both make the `equals` method shorter, and have the `apply` method take care of the sorting, or just do as [Alexey Romanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064342/4541415) suggested, which is why I marked his answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Note that a class implementing `equals` also must override `hashCode` in such a way that equal instances always have the same hash code (this applies to your original question as well). `case class` takes care of this consistency automatically (provided all of parameters are themselves correct in this respect).