# What changes when a case class has a companion object?

Tags: scala, case-class

I originally encountered the behavior below, where code that worked fine when a case class didn't have a companion object would fail to compile when that companion object was defined. I was able to fix it by calling `Bar.apply _` instead of simply `Bar`, but I still don't understand why that is necessary.

I'm trying to use the product-collections library from https://github.com/marklister/product-collections, and it will happily parse a CSV into a case class, but only if that case class has no companion object. This is puzzling, especially since [the documentation suggests](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections/blob/master/shared/src/main/boilerplate/collections/io/CsvParser.scala.template) that the companion object is the ideal place to put additional implicit converters.

I see identical behavior if I define the case class and object in the opposite order, and what I see in the REPL matches my IDE.

What is the effect of defining a companion object to a case class? I would expect it to be precisely nothing, since the companion object (with apply and unapply methods) is already defined by virtue of being a case class.

```
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParser
import com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParser

scala> case class Foo(i: Int, d: Double, s: String)
defined class Foo

scala> case class Bar(i: Int, d: Double, s: String); object Bar {}
defined class Bar
defined object Bar

scala> CsvParser(Foo).parse(new java.io.StringReader("1, 2.4,\"hi\"\n3, 8.9,\"bye\""))
res0: Seq[Foo] = List(Foo(1,2.4,hi), Foo(3,8.9,bye))

scala> CsvParser(Bar).parse(new java.io.StringReader("1, 2.4,\"hi\"\n3, 8.9,\"bye\""))
<console>:14: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, T22) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF22[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,T22,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, T21) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF21[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,T21,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, T20) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF20[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,T20,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, T19) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF19[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,T19,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, T18) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF18[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,T18,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, T17) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF17[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,T17,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF16[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,T16,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF15[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,T15,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF14[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,T14,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF13[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,T13,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF12[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,T12,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF11[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF10[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF9[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF8[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF7[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF6[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF5[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, T4, F](f: (T1, T2, T3, T4) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF4[T1,T2,T3,T4,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, T3, F](f: (T1, T2, T3) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF3[T1,T2,T3,F] <and>
  [T1, T2, F](f: (T1, T2) => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF2[T1,T2,F] <and>
  [T1, F](f: T1 => F)com.github.marklister.collections.io.CsvParserF1[T1,F]
 cannot be applied to (Bar.type)
       CsvParser(Bar).parse(new java.io.StringReader("1, 2.4,\"hi\"\n3, 8.9,\"bye\""))
       ^

scala> CsvParser(Bar.apply _).parse(new java.io.StringReader("1, 2.4,\"hi\"\n3, 8.9,\"bye\""))
res1: Seq[Bar] = List(Bar(1,2.4,hi), Bar(3,8.9,bye))
```

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827510/how-to-override-apply-in-a-case-class-companion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto generated companion object of your case class `Foo` will extend `(Int, Double, String) => Foo`. If you define the companion object yourself for the case class `Bar` the compiler will no longer automatically add that inheritance relation.

For more information you can take a look at [SI-3664](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3664).