# Swap constructor arguments

Tags: scala

Is it possible to swap the arguments of a constructor?
Consider the following example:

```
case class Foo(a:Int, b:Int) {
  if (a > b) {
    val tmp = a
    a = b
    b = tmp
  }
}
```

The compiler throws an error because I reassign to val `a` at line 4 which is perfectly fine. However, I need immutable objects. Therefore, declaring `a` and `b` as variables is not an option.

Is there a known pattern how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Make an inner swap method:

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int) {
  def ifSwap = if (a > b) Foo(b, a) else this
}

val f1 = Foo(1,2).ifSwap // the result is Foo(1,2)
val f2 = Foo(2,1).ifSwap // the result is Foo(1,2)
```

If you want to preserve immutability then to change state you need either return new instance on each modification, or use some hardcore ways like [Lenses](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Lens.html), [State](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html), 
[Records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless#extensible-records), etc... And as Prof. Odersky told on SD'13 talk, there are situations when you shouldn't be afraid of `vars`

Comment: You may also define a helper method on the companion object `def foo(a: Int, b: Int) = Foo(a, b).ifSwap` instead of repeating `.ifSwap` everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose what you want to achieve that every instance of `Foo` has ordered its pair of values, is that right?

One possibility is not to make the class `case` and instead define its construction and extraction yourself. The class won't inherit from product, no pretty default `toString` etc., but otherwise it's usable just as a case class:

```
class Foo private (val a: Int, val b: Int);
object Foo {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int): Foo =
    if (a < b)
      new Foo(a, b)
    else
      new Foo(b, a)

    def unapply(f: Foo): Option[(Int,Int)] = Some((f.a, f.b))
}

// test:
def printFoo(f: Foo) = f match {
  case Foo(x, y) => println(x + ", " + y);
}
printFoo(Foo(1,2))
printFoo(Foo(3,2))
```

---

See also:

- [How to override apply in a case class companion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5827510/1333025)
- [Scala: is it possible to override default case class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660975/1333025)
- [Overload constructor for Scala's Case Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2400794/1333025)

Comment: Turns out you can keep your *case* cake and eat it too. I mean keep your *case* class and still make the constructor private. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you can make the case class constructor private! Extending on @PetrPudlák answers, I make the constructor private and define a `foo` helper to create the case class objects:

```
case class Foo private (a: Int, b: Int)
object Foo {
  def foo(x: Int, y: Int) = if (x > y) Foo(y, x) else Foo(x, y)
}
```

Then I just use `foo` to instantiate the well formed `Foo` objects and the rest of the case class functionality works as expected (equality, hashcode, unapply):

```
import Foo._

foo(1, 2)                                 //> res0: worksheets.so.Foo = Foo(1,2)
foo(2, 1)                                 //> res1: worksheets.so.Foo = Foo(1,2)
foo(3, 4) == foo(4, 3)                    //> res2: Boolean = true
// Foo(4, 2) does not compile

// extractor/pattern matching works:
val Foo(a, b) = foo(10,1)                 //> a  : Int = 1
                                          //| b  : Int = 10
```

You could also name `foo` as something more meaningful like `OrderedFoo` or `NormalFoo`.

Comment: If the intention is for the case class Foo to reliably represent an ADT (Abstract Data Type) such that a is always assumed to be less than or equal to b, then it is possible to produce an "invalid" instance of this ADT via the following; "val foo1 = Foo(1, 2); val foo2 = foo1.copy(a = 10)" Also, due to case classes implementing java.io.Serializable, it is also possible to subvert valid values via a text editor and deserialization. I cover the steps to handle these issues in this answer on another question thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538287/501113

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Foo {
  def swapped(b: Int, a: Int) = Foo(a=a, b=b)
}
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined module Foo
defined class Foo

scala> Foo.swapped(1, 2) == Foo(2, 1)
res0: Boolean = true
```