# withDefaultValue in case class

Tags: scala, dictionary, case-class

simple case class:

```
case class country(name: String, townPopulation: Map[String,Int])
```

with simple example:

```
scala> val germany = country("Germany",Map("Berlin" -> 100000, "Saale" -> 4000))
germany: country = country(Germany,Map(Berlin -> 100000, Saale -> 4000))

scala> germany.townPopulation("Berlin")
res77: Int = 100000

scala> germany.townPopulation("blergh")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: blergh
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
  at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
  ... 42 elided
```

I would like to return 0 for towns that dont exist, this can be done when declaring a val:

```
scala> val germany = country("Germany",Map("Berlin" -> 100000, "Saale" -> 4000).withDefaultValue(0))
germany: country = country(Germany,Map(Berlin -> 100000, Saale -> 4000))

scala> germany.townPopulation("fdhjkjhkhjdfg")
res79: Int = 0
```

but I can not figure out how to do it in one place, at least not when it is a case class, I would like something simple as the following, but I am obviously doing it wrong:

```
scala> case class country(name: String, townPopulation: Map[String,Int].withDefaultValue(0))
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '.' found.
case class country(name: String, townPopulation: Map[String,Int].withDefaultValue(0))
                                                                ^
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but ')' found.
case class country(name: String, townPopulation: Map[String,Int].withDefaultValue(0))
```

Is there a short simple path to a solution that has 0 as defaultValue always?

Comment: Just reading in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37588616/409976's answer that the value == population, there seems to be a difference between "having a population, i.e. a key exists for the given city/town" and not existing in the map at all. With `0`, such distinction is lost. Perhaps `Option[Int]` is not a better fit for the value in the map's key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val germany = country("Germany",
                      Map("Berlin" -> 100000, "Saale" -> 4000)
                        .withDefaultValue(0))
```

---

Edit (after OP's answer):

My bad! Should have read more thoroughly your question.

As stated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664004/2681752): *You do not have the option of changing the way the default constructor stores its parameters (e.g. by modifying the parameters before they are stored as vals) […]*.

An alternate solution would be to declare a regular `class` along with its *companion object*:

```
class Country(val name: String, val townPopulation: Map[String, Int])
case object Country {
  def apply(name: String, townPopulation: Map[String, Int]) =
    new Country(name, townPopulation.withDefaultValue(0))
}
```

This would allow you to declare countries using the nice syntax:

```
val germany = Country("Germany", Map("Berlin" -> 100000, "Saale" -> 4000))
assert(germany.townPopulation("Berlin") == 100000)
assert(germany.townPopulation("Blergh") == 0)
```

But note that, as it is **not** a `case class` you won't get the usual `case class` perks such as:

```
// Compiler will give you
//    "object Country is not a case class,
//     nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member"
//germany match {
//  case Country(a, b) => println("It won't compile! Not a case class")
//}
```

Depending on your use case, you could go the long hard road and implement methods `unapply` and `unapplySeq` to retrieve such behavior if needed!

Comment: I have that one in there, it does it, but you have to use withDefaultValue everytime, I would prefer to just declare directly it in the case class and never have to worry about it later

Comment: Well there was not the simple magic solution I had hoped for, but thanks for explaining why not :)

Answer (score 2):

I see few possible ways:

- add auxiliary method which encapsulate logic of default value

  `def population(town : String) : Int = townPopulation.getOrElse(town, 0)`
- add method to companion object with same purpose

  `def withDefault(name: String, townPopulation: Map[String, Int]) : country =
      country(name, townPopulation.withDefaultValue(0))`

Answer (score 1):

Use map.get(), which returns an `Option`:

```
println germany.townPopulation.get("blergh").getOrElse(0)
// or, more concisely:
println germany.townPopulation.getOrElse("blergh", 0)
```

Ah, on re-reading your question, you want to hard-code the default value in the case class. I guess you'll have to mess with the apply() method.

Comment: `Map.getOrElse` looks better imo