# Named constructors in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, named-constructor

Are there named constructors in Scala?

Comment: Downvoted because of question's ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends what you mean with "named constructors", but yes you can overload constructors
see [Overload constructor for Scala's Case Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400794/overload-constructor-for-scalas-case-classes)

Also you can put factory methods in a Companion Objects for your class (static singleton).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there are but the named constructor idiom can be supported by object methods calling class constructors. Typically in Scala the apply method is used as it can use function call syntax:

```
val mc = MyClass(a, b, c)
```

with the following definition

```
object MyClass {def apply(a: Atype, b: Btype, c: Ctype) = new MyClass(a, b, c)}
```

or if you want something like

```
val mc = MyClass.create(a, b, c)
```

it would be simply

```
object MyClass {def create(a: Atype, b: Btype, c: Ctype)  = new MyClass(a, b, c)}
```

You are not limited to the companion object either, however private and protected constructors would require you to use the companion object directly or as a proxy to access the class constructor(s),