# Is new required when calling a Scala auxiliary constructor?

Tags: scala, constructor

When I run the following in a worksheet, everything is as expected.

```
case class P(x: Int, xs: Set[Int]) {
  def this(x: Int) = this(x, Set[Int]())
}
P(1, Set())                   //> res0: worksheet.P = P(1,Set())
new P(1)                      //> res0: worksheet.P = P(1,Set())
```

When I leave off the **new** I get a compiler diagnostic that says:

```
  - not enough arguments for method apply: (x: Int, xs: Set[Int])worksheet.P in object P. Unspecified value parameter xs.
```

The same diagnostic appears in a regular .scala file.

Is this a compiler bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

Without new you're calling not constructor but *factory method* which is auto-generated by the compiler for case classes. You can define new one:

```
case class P(x: Int, xs: Set[Int])
object P { 
  def apply(x: Int): P = P(x, Set[Int]())
}

scala> P(1, Set()) 
res2: P = P(1,Set())

scala> P(1)
res3: P = P(1,Set())
```

Alternatively you can use define two *constructors*, but in your particular case I would go with default value:

```
 case class P(x: Int, xs: Set[Int] = Set[Int]())
```

See also [this answer which showcases similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2401153/298389) and [tour on case classes](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/case-classes-are-cool)

Comment: See comment on ntalbs's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Defining case class will also create factory method of class name, so you don't have to use `new` while creating an instance. So the following code works file:

```
P(1, Set())
```

Your class also have constructors, the following code will work fine, too:

```
new P(1, Set())
new P(1)
```

In the case of `P(1)`, there's no such method, so the error occurs.

Comment: I want Scala to be intuitive and understandable from one's first encounter with it. The documentation says (unequivocally as far as I can tell) that case classes don't require "new". This answer seems to be telling me that the documentation is wrong. Worse it seems to be telling me that I have to understand how Scala is implemented to know how to use it. That's not good.

Comment: "The documentation says (unequivocally as far as I can tell) that case classes don't require "new"" Which documentation?