# Overriding case class constructor

Tags: scala

When attempt to overload constructor argument of case class :

```
 case class Node(var isVisited: Boolean, adjacentNodes: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Node], name: String) {
    def this(name : String) = this(isVisited , adjacentNodes , name)
  }
```

receive this error : `not found: value isVisited`

Should this not work as explained in accepted answer of :

[Overload constructor for Scala's Case Classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400794/overload-constructor-for-scalas-case-classes)

However,this works, although not using a case class :

```
 class Node(var isVisited: Boolean, adjacentNodes: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Node], name: String) {
        def adjacentNodes(): scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Node] = { adjacentNodes }
        def name(): String = { name }
      }

      object Node {
        def apply(name: String): Node = new Node(false, scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Node](), name)
      }
```

Comment: @Gábor Bakos question updated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isVisited` and `adjacentNodes` do not exist for the overloaded constructor. It looks like you intend to use `false` and an empty list if they are not provided:

```
case class Node(var isVisited: Boolean, adjacentNodes: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Node], name: String) {
    def this(name : String) = this(false, scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[Node](), name)
}
```